# iOS TableView Index Value on Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, indexpath

I am using table view in my Swift project. The problem is with table view cell index path value. When the table gets loaded initially, the index values are ok. But as soon as I scroll my table view the cell index paths change and the ids I get from a data array are wrong. Googling results that it is because of reusable cell like thing. Here's my view controller code:

```
//
//  ProjectsController.swift
//  PMUtilityTool
//
//  Created by Muhammad Ali on 9/23/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Genetech Solutions. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ProjectsController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    var ProjectsArray: Array<Project> = []

    @IBOutlet weak var ProjectsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

        // Remove indenting of cell
        if self.ProjectsTableView.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:")) {
            self.ProjectsTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
        if self.ProjectsTableView.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")) {
            self.ProjectsTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }

        self.ProjectsTableView.layoutIfNeeded()

        // Get projects
        getProjects()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

    // MARK: - TableView Datasource
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.ProjectsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // print("clicked")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ProjectTableViewCell {

        print(indexPath.row)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProjectViewCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! ProjectTableViewCell

        // Remove indenting of cell
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        // Set project name
        cell.ProjectName.text = "\((indexPath.row)+1). \(self.ProjectsArray[indexPath.row].ProjectName)"

        // Set action button
        cell.ActionButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.ActionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProjectsController.projectActions(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    }

    func reloadTableViewAfterDelay()
    {
        ProjectsTableView.performSelector(#selector(UITableView.reloadData), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
    }

    @IBAction func projectActions(sender: UIButton) {
        let index = sender.tag

        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: self.ProjectsArray[index].ProjectName, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        // Report Progress
        let reportProgressAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Report Progress", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowReportProgress", sender: sender)
        })

        // Cancel
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        })

        optionMenu.addAction(reportProgressAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let button = sender where segue.identifier == "ShowReportProgress" {
            let upcoming: ReportProgressController = segue.destinationViewController as! ReportProgressController
            print(self.ProjectsArray[button.tag].ProjectId)
            upcoming.ProjectId = self.ProjectsArray[button.tag].ProjectId
            upcoming.ProjectName = self.ProjectsArray[button.tag].ProjectName
        }

    }

    // MARK: Get Projects Function
    func getProjects() -> Void
    {

        var params = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
        params =  ["user_id":CFunctions.getSession("id")]

        WebServiceController.getAllProjects(params){ (type, response, message) -> Void in

            if (type == ResponseType.kResponseTypeFail)
            {

                // Show Error
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error(s)", message:"Unable to load projects.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

            }
            else
            {
                //debugPrint(response)

                if(response.count>0)
                {
                    self.ProjectsArray = response
                }
                else
                {
                    // Show Error
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error(s)", message:"No projects found.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                }

                self.reloadTableViewAfterDelay()

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want each cell's index value to be intact whether I scroll down or up.

Comment: What do you mean by "cell's index value to be intact"? do you want it to be static? if that's what you mean then you can't do that. Cell's indexPath is used to determine the location of each cell.

Comment: `for example, i have 20 rows, it shows 8 rows initially (at a time). i have added print(indexPath.row) in it. now when i scroll down, it still prints the indexPath of previous rows.

Comment: like this: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
8
9
10
1
0
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
7

Comment: So, you have a problem, indication you got, when you print indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Ali please remove the unwanted code, and only put the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath. Because there is no need of any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your iPhone screen, for example you can see 5 cells at a time.

1. > So, first time, when you load tableView cellForRowAtindexPAth method will be called for first 5
   >   cells.

   "As you mentioned, first time you are loading and tableView indexes
   are correct."
2. > Now when you scroll down, cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be called
   >   for only 6 and 7.

   "Till this time everything works ok, as you mentioned. AS you can see      overall indexpath as intact 1,2, **3,4,5,6,7**."

   *Dark cells are currently visible on your screen.
3. > Now when you scroll up **{2 cells}**. Now you can see the current   visible cell's on your screen are **1,2,3,4,5**.

> Here, cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be called for ONLY cells numbered  2,1.

**Because cell numbers 3,4,5 are already loaded/visible in your screen.**

So, your Print log will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,1.

Comment: but what if i have an array with indexes, and my table iterates over that array to print its contents (in cells). as soon as i click action button (against any particular cell), this cell's index should be passed to button's action method, there i have called an action sheet, in that action sheet there's another option "Report Progress", clicking that option should now get the index of cell and by using that index, extract proper projectId (from array), where array's index and cell's index remains same. hope you get my point.

Comment: Hi, Ali. I got your point. Your code is correct.  If you run your project it will get the correct indexes. You run your project and try. I am sure with your code.

Comment: It is not that you see the indexes.Please reply.

Comment: Hi, Ali, I have edited the question in speed. Please do not read, if you do not like the edited. I will edit better.

Comment: Hi Ali, Have you got why you are not getting indexPath.row 'intact' ?

Comment: Got it..!! Everything was okay. The only issue was with my ProjectsArray. It had wrong data (being returned from a web service). Thanks for your time and patience Arpit.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate you with love. Thanks for the appreciation. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You should add `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` to your class. and set it `ProjectsTableView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get indexPath of button using tableViewCell's hierarchy.

```
 @IBAction func projectActions(sender: UIButton) {
  let button = sender as! UIButton
  let view = button.superview!
  let cell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell
  let indexPath = self.reloadTableViewAfterDelay.indexPathForCell(cell)
  let index = indexPath.row
}

 if let button = sender where segue.identifier == "ShowReportProgress" {
       let upcoming: ReportProgressController =  segue.destinationViewController as! ReportProgressController
       let view = button.superview!
       let cell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell
       let indexPath = self.reloadTableViewAfterDelay.indexPathForCell(cell)
       let index = indexPath.row
       print(self.ProjectsArray[index].ProjectId)
       upcoming.ProjectId = self.ProjectsArray[index].ProjectId
       upcoming.ProjectName = self.ProjectsArray[index].ProjectName
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to get indexPath of button using tableViewCell's than used below code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 10
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId as String)! as UITableViewCell

    let ActionButton : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UIButton

    ActionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.projectActions(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func projectActions(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
    print(indexPath?.row)

}
```